# WebSphere cannot start webapp instrumented by cobertura

Tags: websphere, code-coverage, cobertura

I instrumented a few classes, packed them in war and ear. Install this ear in WebSphere.
Now this Application Status is Stopped.
Should I place cobertura.jar anywere? Is where my mistake?

Comment: You're more likely to get productive responses if you can provide some more detail about your problem, possibly the code which isn't working.  Without more detail it's hard for potential answer-ers to help out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Websphere Application server allowes ear to be deployed/installed, so build you application ear with cobertura instrumented classes.
2. Copy the cobertura.ser file generated by default in `target/cobertura/cobertura.ser` location in your system while maven build, in to `../AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/` location of WAS.
3. Start the server
4. run some testes.
5. Stop the server. cobertura.ser will get updated.

Run the cobertura report.

Answer (score 0):

I solve a lot of my problem while read this doc: http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/instrumentingDeploymentArtifact.html

Found my cobertura.ser in /ibm/was/profiles/*profile*/

Answer (score -1):

Cobertura instruments classes to be able *"[to identify which parts of your Java program are lacking test coverage](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)"*

I think it adds its own classes so they collect the information and at the end of the test coverage phase write this down to a data store. With that said, I'd expect `cobertura.jar` and some other jars should be included in the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

To get more insights on the issue, have a look at `SystemOut.log` of the server instance. It's in `[WEBSPHERE_HOME]/profiles/[PROFILE_NAME]/logs/server1` directory.